# linq to SQL no actualiza los datos desde que instale visual studio 2017

Tags: linq-to-sql

Desde que instale visual studio 2017 no me actualiza los datos en la base de datos con linq. revise muchas veces el código y esta todo bien, Es mas desde otros proyectos también me dejo de actualizar. Creo que es un problema ya de la clase LinQ pero la cuestión es que no puedo actualizar nada. Con try y catch no me tira error. Ya no se que hacer estoy medio desesperado. Uso Visual Studio 2017 con SQL SQLSERVER 2017

Es un ejemplo que he creado para poder mostrar el problema. Pero ya probé con otros proyectos que funcionaban perfectamente pero ahora no me funcionan

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            afiliados af = db.afiliados.Where(x => x.DNI == 
            "26954776").Single();
            af.ASAMBLEA = 1;
            af.VOTO = 1;
            af.TELEFONO_SOCIO = 111;
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("problema");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Luego ejecuto la consulta en el SQLServer 2016 y no modifica.

```
select  * from afiliados where dni = '26954776'
```

muestra como resultado los datos sin modificar

es decir no se modifican los campos ASAMBLEA , VOTO, TELEFONO_SOCIO.
Ya instale y desinstale el visual studio y el SQLServer y nada sigue igual. ¿Sera que con VS2017 cambio la forma de trabajar con linqtosql?
Si pueden ayudarme por favor. GRACIAS !!!!!

Comment: Considere el colocar mas información para poderte ayudar. ¿Tiene algún mensaje de error?. ¿Depuro el código? ¿Al depurar los valores son correctos? ¿La cadena de conexión esta bien? ¿Que tipo de proyecto es: Consola, web, MVC Asp..?

Comment: @Softwarelover ya puse mas información si puedes ayudarme por favor

Answer (score 0):

Por falta de tiempo no pude responderle rápido. Le respondo con la solución que halle por si aun le es útil.

Por lo que entiendo de su código. Usted lo que busca es actualizar un registro usando EF.
Trate de simular su situación y esta es la solución que encontré:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya seria cuestión de que adapte el código